# .reset() method results in error in typescript to reset forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using document.getelementbyID().reset(); to reset form values. But I am receiving an error in typescript.

```
Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

I am using this feature:

```
const resetButton = () => {
    document.getElementById('compliance').reset();
}

<button onClick={resetButton}>
Reset
</button>
```

This feature worked in javascript but not in typpescript.

How can I use it. I have tried these methods but none work.

1.

```
 (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('compliance)).reset;
```

I received this error.

```
JSX element 'HTMLInputElement' has no corresponding closing tag.
```

2. 

```
let inputreset = (document.getElementById('compliance) as HTMLInputElement).reset;
```

I received this error.

```
Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to reset a form, cast it to `HTMLFormElement`, which does have the `reset` method ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=43&pln=1&pc=58#code/BQEw9gxgrgtgpgOwC4DoDmckFEA2d7IBCAngJIjADkEYMADjgJYCGCEclAlAATMDO3ABIAVALIAZAGJgATjFz5ESTihlw%20mANwBYAFB6gA)):

```
const resetButton = () => {
  (document.getElementById('compliance') as HTMLFormElement).reset();
}
```

A solution that would be more React friendly is to use a ref:

```
const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement>();

const resetButton = () => {
  formRef.current?.reset(); // note conditional chaining `?.`
}

return (
  <form ref={formRef}>
    {/* Other form controls */}
  
    <button onClick={resetButton}>
    Reset
    </button>
  </form>
)
```

The best solution would be to set [button type to `reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset), and then you won't need the function at all:

```
<button type="reset">
Reset
</button>
```